# Reactjs SPA stopped working after splitting code, ( static bundle is not loading from AWS S3)

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack-4

My website has been working well before my recent change. The website front-end is on reactjs, and bundle is on aws s3. Everything is good till this point.

Now because of huge size of static bundle and also to optimize my code, I started splitting code via webpack [split code](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), lazy loading of react component and dynamic import. I am using [webpack-bundle-tracker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-tracker) to create bundle because my back-end is on django. This new setup is working well on my local environment.

```
DEV environment: 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/frontend/main.35952edee77e6e3f52e5.bundle.js" ></script>
```

And this loads very well formatted code to load on my local environment:

```
DEV environment:

/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
/******/    function webpackJsonpCallback(data) {
/******/        var chunkIds = data[0];
/******/        var moreModules = data[1];
/******/
/******/
/******/        // add "moreModules" to the modules object,
/******/        // then flag all "chunkIds" as loaded and fire callback
/******/        var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, resolves = [];
/******/        for(;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
/******/            chunkId = chunkIds[i];
/******/            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(installedChunks, chunkId) && installedChunks[chunkId]) {
/******/                resolves.push(installedChunks[chunkId][0]);
/******/            }
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
/******/        }
/******/        for(moduleId in moreModules) {
/******/            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moreModules, moduleId)) {
/******/                modules[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/        if(parentJsonpFunction) parentJsonpFunction(data);
/******/
/******/        while(resolves.length) {
/******/            resolves.shift()();
/******/        }
/******/
/******/    };
```

But when I deploy code on heroku, and push static bundles on aws s3, it stops working. It doesn't throw any error, so I am not able to understand the reason of this issue.

```
Prod env

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecmsdjango-main.s3.amazonaws.com/staticfiles/main.54a39fc868c800757af7.bundle.js" ></script>
```

Further if I click on the above aws link I can see the static content, but this is not in a good format as I could see on my local environment.

```
 Prod env

(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[0],{1003:function(e,t,n){},1004:function(e,t,n){"use strict";n.r(t);var r=n(0),a=n.n(r),o=n(81),s=n(12),i=n(38),c=n(1),l=n.n(c),u=n(14);function p(e){return(p="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof e})(e)}function m(e,t){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var r=t[n];r.enumerable=r.enumerable||!1,r.configurable=!0,"value"in r&&(r.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(e,r.key,r)}}function d(e,t){return!t||"object"!==p(t)&&"function"!=typeof t?function(e){if(void 0!==e)return e;throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called")}(e):t}function h(e){return(h=Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.getPrototypeOf:function(e){return e.__proto__||Object.getPrototypeOf(e)})(e)}function f(e,t){return(f=Object.setPrototypeOf||function(e,t){return e.__proto__=t,e})(e,t)}var g=function(){function i(){var e,t,a;!function(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}(this,i);for(var n=arguments.length,r=new Array(n),o=0;o<n;o++)r[o]=arguments[o];return d(a,(t=a=d(this,(e=h(i)).call.apply(e,[this].concat(r))),a.state={username:"",password:""},a.onSubmit=function(e){e.preventDefault(),a.props.login(a.state.username,a.state.password)},a.onChange=function(e){return a.setState((t={},n=e.target.name,r=e.target.value,n in t?Object.defineProperty(t,n,{value:r,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):t[n]=r,t));var t,n,r},t))}var e,t,n;return
```

> So basically the website doesn't load any thing (its blank) but underlying bundles have static content in it. So it appears to me that something is linked with the loader or could
>   be the way aws s3 loads the chunks, but I haven't got root cause yet, please help me to fix this.
>   For example: [website](https://www.ecmsdjango.com/) is showing old version before code split, if I deploy the latest code, it will be blank.

P.S. For now I am tagging it with react js, django as well because main reason of code split was optimization of my react front-end, and bridging it with django but both of these tags can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because of webpack split chunks optimization config, I have removed that config from prod and it was all looking okay. I have not this extra optimization in webpack dev config.
I am marking it as an answer, because now I know the root cause and its not an aws s3 or webpack issue, and overall its no longer a problem now.